# Django Rest Framework nested model as list instead of dict

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to have a nested model as a *List* instead of *Dict*?
I'm trying to implement it  with *ListField* but having a hard time.
Following a sample to better explain what I'm trying to do.

**Sample Models:**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Track(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name="tracks")
```

**Sample Serializer:**

```
Class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
    model = Track
    fields = ['number', 'title']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True)
    model = Album
    fields = ['name', 'tracks']
```

**Wrong output resulted from the code above:**

```
{
    "name": "ALBUM NAME",
    "tracks": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "title": "TRACK TITLE"
        },
        {
            "number": 2,
            "title": "OTHER TRACK TITLE"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
{
    "name": "ALBUM NAME",
    "tracks": [
        [1, "TRACK TITLE"],
        [2, "OTHER TRACK TITLE"]
    ]
}
```

Comment: The format you are trying to build is odd, but it's still achievable using a `SerializerMethodField`. Unless you want it to be writable as well, in which case you'll have to implement your own serializer subclass.

Comment: It is indeed odd/weird but I was able to accomplish it with the `SerializerMethodField`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: an album serializer with one field that is the result of a method and can be anything (*SerializerMethodField*)

**serializers.py**

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    track_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['name', 'track_list']
    class get_track_list(self, obj):
        output = []
        for i in Track.objects.filter(album = obj.id):
            output.append([i.number, i.title])
        return output
```

This returns me an JSON with attributes "name" and "track_list", just the way I needed:

```
{
    "name": "ALBUM NAME",
    "track_list": [
        [1, "TRACK TITLE"],
        [2, "OTHER TRACK TITLE"]
    ]
}
```